# How to embed an Instagram carousel in particular index?

Tags: javascript, instagram, carousel, embed

I'm using https://api.instagram.com/oembed to embed an Instagram carousel (e.g. https://www.instagram.com/p/BvRwa1tArMo).

I was wondering if there's a way to select the index of the carousel image. For example, in this case, I'd like the embedding to show the second image instead of the first one.

My simplified code is:

```js
$.get(
  'https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/BvRwa1tArMo&hidecaption=1&omitscript=1',
  function (data) {
    $('#ig-post').html(data.html);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
<div id="ig-post"></div>
```

(For some reason it doesn't fully work here but it does in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/43veku7t/)

Comment: I would say it's not possible.The final content is basically an iframe pointing to `https://www.instagram.com/p/BvRwa1tArMo/embed`. Besides, `instgrm.Embeds` only provides one function: `process`. Neither the documentation about [embedding](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/) nor the [help](https://help.instagram.com/269314186824048) about posting multiple photos say anything about setting up the initial/default photo.

Answer (score 3):

Well you could take the width of the `li._-1_m6` (I hate obfuscated class names with a passion) element, which in the context of the jsfiddle is 658.406px and then take a look at the `translateX` property of the `.MreMs` class (see if there's any more of a robust way to determine this). At a `translateX` of 0, youre at index 0, then at a `translateX` of -658 (and change) you're at index 1 (or -1 i guess?). All that being said, I'm not sure if you'll even be able to access this info due to it being an iframe and the whole CORS debacle. I'm not sure what Instagram allows.

If that doesn't work, then I'm sorry to say, there's no way.